# SSLv23 does not allow sslv3 clients to connect

Tags: c, ssl, curl, openssl

I am trying to create a https server that uses the ssl context. Everything works out fine for this code for TLS clients

```
 ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());

    long options = SSL_OP_ALL |SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 |SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3;
```

This effectively disables sslv2 and sslv3 and enables certain bug fixes.

I want to keep the disabling sslv3 part optional. But removing of SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 still does not make sslv3 work.

```
 ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());

    long options = SSL_OP_ALL |SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 ; // SSLV3 still does not work
```

I use curl as the client:

```
curl -vk --sslv3 "https://IP/hello_world"

* Server aborted the SSL handshake
* Closing connection 0
```

For non sslv3 everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the configure section of the library. It was compiled with no ssl2 or ssl3 as below

> no-ssl2 no-ssl3

Hence sslv3 did not work with sslv23.